# Área de comentários sobrepondo rodapé do site!

Tags: html, css, facebook

Olá, tenho uma área de comentários em meu site que fiz utilizando a API do Facebook.
O problema é que quando alguém envia algum comentário, este fica sobrepondo o layout do rodapé. já tentei usar `position: relative`, `position: absolute` e `position: fixed`, nenhuma funcionou.

Vou deixar uma print para entenderem melhor.
Agradeço a quem ajudar.

[image: imagem]

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML respectivo a essa parte? Já tentaste `z-index` ou `overflow: hidden;` ?

Comment: Sua questão não tem haver com PHP, leia isto por favor Jean: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) e principalmente [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Vou testar isso Sergio, obrigado. E Guilherme, achei que fosse um fórum de ajuda em programação. já vi muita frescura por aqui em relação a regras.

Comment: Olá Jean por favor não se ofenda, isto isto não é frescura e também não é um fórum, isto é um "Q&A" (Question and Answer), ou seja não aqui as perguntas tem que ser claras, deve-se usar as TAGS corretas e não é um local apropriado para debates como geralmente são os fóruns. Espero que entenda e seja bem vindo!

Comment: Tudo bem Guilherme, vou dar uma lida nas regras que você me passou. Coloquei a tag PHP porque meu código foi feito em php. tanto que é um site em joomla. achei que fizesse parte.

Comment: Então Sergio, coloquei isso e não funcionou como eu queria =/
Não sei se posso postar uma print aqui, caso não seja permitido peço desculpas, aqui está: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51209955/wdawd.png

Como hidden, ele fica atrás do rodapé, então coloquei o overflow do tipo auto e apareceu aquele scroll do lado. o código não consigo pega-lo, pois trata-se de um módulo do joomla. estou estilizando via css mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado por compreender Jean, procure usar as TAGs devem ser sobre o problema da questão.

Comment: Facilitaria te ajudar se você nos ajudar a entender o problema. Edite a pergunta e coloque o código HTML e o CSS (somente as regras do seu rodapé).

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o problema seja com algum `float` no container do chat. Tente utilizar o estilo `clear: both` em algum elemento logo após o chat, mas que esteja dentro do container.

Verifique também se o container tem uma altura definida. Se puder, deixe-o apenas com um `min-height` e não um `height` fixo.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar isto:

```css
z-index: 50000;
```